# API gateway and load balancer concept

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, api-gateway

I already did lot of google and even went through this article ([Load balancer and API Gateway confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61174839/load-balancer-and-api-gateway-confusion)) but still i am confused about load balancer and API gateway relation and how incoming request will route if i have implemented both load balancer and api gateway, currently my understanding is

Client request ---> API gateway ---> Load balancer ( nginx) ---> real Api's.

Please explain in layman term.

Answer (score 2):

API Gateway has support to proxy traffic to a load balancer. This load balancer will forward traffic between 1 or more instances.

API Gateway can modify/validate requests before they reach your load balancer, as well as providing the ability to cache responses. It also provides the ability to distribute traffic to different load balancers or even services (such as Lambdas) based on path based routing.

Additionally API Gateway includes additional features such as the ability to run canary based deployments to run multiple copies of the application in parallel whilst shifting traffic between.